# Data flow from Nginx access log -> Rsyslog or Syslog -> Fluentd -> Kinesis

Tags: apache, nginx, amazon-kinesis, fluentd, rsyslog

I am working on passing `nginx` access logs to `Fluentd` to `aws kinesis` to `AWS S3 via kinesis firehose`. nginx logs will be pushed to `AWS Glacier` during `log rotation`.

I am at the initial steps where I need need to pass nginx access logs to  fluentd via syslog/rsyslog.

Nginx version used is 1.14.

My OS is :

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
```

There are many ways to push nginx logs to rsyslog.

**Way 1 :** Using module imfile , and updating rsyslog.conf as shown in https://petermolnar.net/log-nginx-to-rsyslog/

**Way 2 :** Updating nginx.conf to write directly in syslog. I am worried this will slow nginx down during high traffix. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#logging-to-syslog

**Way 3:** Skip rsyslog/syslog and directly pass data from nginx to fluentd via module https://github.com/fluent/nginx-fluentd-module . Here i am worried that this module is reliable or no and also if nginx should not become less responsive due to this module being used.

> What is the best way to achieve the goal , the goal is for realtime
>   data flow from nginx access logs to fluentd , without blocking nginx
>   to serve requests.

Comment: Waiting for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no replies for over a month, Sharing the way that I chose.

Using module imfile , and updating rsyslog.conf as shown in https://petermolnar.net/log-nginx-to-rsyslog/